# PRAW Comment and Sticky

Tags: python, praw

I want to comment to a post, and sticky it straight away:

```
for submission in sub:
    if (submission.is_video or os.path.splitext(submission.url)[-1] in [".gif", ".gifv", ".mp4", ".webm"]) and submission.id not in get_old_submissions():
        submission.reply(MESSAGE)
```

I've tried iterating through the submissions comments, checking if the body is equal to the message, but my comment doesn't seem to show up at all:

```
        print(submission.comments.list())
```

Just gives `[]`. Is there perhaps an easy way of getting the id of the new comment so I can pin it straight away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.reply()` [returns a Comment object](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/submission.html#praw.models.Submission.reply), so you can just assign that to a variable and then [sticky it](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/other/commentmoderation.html#praw.models.reddit.comment.CommentModeration.distinguish):

```
comment = submission.reply()
comment.mod.distinguish(sticky=True)
```